# Using fastText Sentence Vector as an Input Feature

Tags: text-classification, fasttext, mlp

I want to use the fastText Sentence Vector as an input Feature.

```
vector = model.get_sentence_vector('Original Sentence')
```

I am attempting to perform Binary Classification of sentences using MLPs and will train the algorithm using the fixed sized feature generated by the above code. Is this a plausible thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the mean of the word embeddings, i.e., tokenize the sentence, look up embeddings for all words computing an average. In this way, you will get a NumPy array that you can use as an input to whatever classifier you want. Depending on the classification task, it might be useful to remove function words first.

[Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html) has a richer Python API than FastText itself. If you just want to quickly train a classifier, the best option is using the command line interface of [FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText#text-classification).

Comment: But can I use get_sentence_vector? I believe this also returns an averaging of words in the sentence.

Comment: Yes, it does the average plus some additional tricks L2 norms.